# Closing forms opened by this form

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I'm writing a chat application for a school project. One of the forms I have is the Contacts form, from which I open different SingleDialogue forms (they are the 1 on 1 chats). I want to make it so that when I close the Contacts form, it closes all the SingleDialogue forms I have opened.

For this I made it so that the Contacts_FormClosing event triggers the Disconnected event in my client object, and in the Contacts form I made a method:

```
private void On_ImDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (SingleDialogue sd in singleChats)
        sd.Close();
}
```

singleChats is the name of a list of SingleDialogue forms opened from the Contacts form. Every time I open another SingleDialogue, it's added to singleChats.
And in the constructor I subscribed it to the Disconnected event in the client object:

```
im.Disconnected += new EventHandler(On_ImDisconnected);
```

So far, what should happen is that when I trigger the Disconnected event in the client object On_ImDisconnected fires up and closes all the SingleDialogues, correct?

But I get an exception saying "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'SingleDialogue' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on".

Alright, then I changed On_ImDisconnected:

```
private void On_ImDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        foreach (SingleDialogue sd in singleChats)
            sd.Close();
    }));
}
```

But now nothing happens. Can you guys help me solve this?

EDIT:

Declaration of the list:

```
List<SingleDialogue> singleChats = new List<SingleDialogue>();
```

Adding new members:

```
private void chatButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SingleDialogue sd = new SingleDialogue(im, chatTextBox.Text);
    singleChats.Add(sd);
    chatTextBox.Text = "";
    sd.Show();
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the declaration of the list, and how you add to it?

Comment: Also add the constructor code of `SingleDialogue`.

Comment: Pretty unclear.  But you are modifying the collection you are iterating by closing these forms, that can't be good.  If closing a SingleDialogue also removes it from the singleChats collection, like it should, then you'll have to make a copy of the collection.  This normally generates an exception, be sure to remove any try/catch code.  Don't put it back until you *know* how to handle the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say skip the list completely. In the constructor of your `SingleDialogue` Form you could add a handler to when the passed parent disconnects, and then close the `SingleDialogue` from within itself.

So if I had to guess what the constructor looks like, you could do something like this:

```
public SingleDialogue(<someFormType> im, string stringThingy)
{
    ...some initialization code...
    im.Disconnected += new EventHandler(im_Disconnected); //Subscribe to the parent's Disconnected event.
}

private void im_Disconnected(object sender, EventArgs e) //When the parent disconnects.
{
    if(this.InvokeRequired) { this.Invoke(() => this.Close()); }
    else { this.Close(); }
}
```

Note that I'm not a native C# developer, so if I did something wrong please tell me. :)

Answer (score 0):

As I understood the scenario, you're keeping a list of forms in Contact form and want to close it.

I suppose your approach is wrong, when you're subscribing every form to the `Disconnected` event. Why not close the form on event trigger from inside of it?

You just need this code in your every `SingleDialogue` instance:

```
//subscribe to event handler, most probably in constructor
im.Disconnected += new EventHandler(On_ImDisconnected);

//close on event fire
private void On_ImDisconnected(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    this.Close();
}
```

You don't need to go through the `list` and close the forms from a parent form.

If I got the question wrong, please correct me.

Comment: I guess you're right. But is there a reason for what I'm doing not working?

Comment: **Hans Passant** explained it in very detail in his comment. That is exactly the reason for not working.